# Powershell 7: Bind my function to shortcut

Tags: powershell

I am trying to bind something like "go to parent dir" to a key command (ctrl+alt+u).

I am new to powershell and still trying to get used to it [but let us be honest, I am a newbie]. I got the command `Split-Path $pwd | Push-Location` which basically does what I want: Go to the parent directory of the current path.

Now I try to bind that command to `Ctrl+Alt+u` but am desperately lost....

I copy-pasted the following which does not work [PSReadLine module is installed, but maybe not the right tool for it??]:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Key Ctrl+Alt+u `
                         -BriefDescription ParentDirectory `
                         -LongDescription "Push parent directory" `
                         -ScriptBlock {
    Split-Path $pwd | Push-Location
}
```

Any help is appreciated. I tried to find useful documentation on this topic to solve it on my own but I was not successful.

Comment: btw. to go to the parent directory you need nothing more than: ```cd ..\```

Comment: that's true, thanks. The advantage (as far as I understood) with Push-Location over Set-Location (which is used when you type cd) is, that you can use Pop-Location (and its alias) to get back to your previous location.   And sill, how to configure a shortcut for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> as defined above works for me however does not show new prompt immediately (I need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> manually)…

- Windows 10
- PowerShell 7.2.6
- module `PSReadLine` 2.1.0)

The following improved user-defined key binding should do the trick:

```
Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+Alt+u `
                         -BriefDescription ParentDirectory `
                         -LongDescription "Push parent directory" `
                         -ScriptBlock {
    Split-Path $pwd | Push-Location
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

Comment: I did not tried `Enter` before, it works indeed.... and with the `...AcceptLine()` it also works as intended, thank you very much!